# Not able to deploy MVC3 to IIS correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, razor, iis-7.5

I've followed the steps to bin deploy my MVC3 application into IIS7, but when I browse it after deployment, it is showing me a list of file similar to ftp website instead running the pages.

[image]

The dlls that are explicitly added in the bin folder of my application are:

- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
- System.Web.Abstractions
- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor

I set security to everyone full control to test, so its not a security issue for sure

and when I try to navigate to home/index for example, IIS wont recognize the path, see error below:
[image]
.net 4 is installed, application pool of the website is .net 4 also

not able to find solutions

What I am missing to do, any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the app pool pipeline set to 'Classic' or 'Integrated'?

Comment: Ok - you need to change it to integrated, things will be a-ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for IIS (this only applies to IIS 7+) to process MVC request, the easiest option is to set your Application Pool pipeline to `Integrated` instead of `Classic`.  Without giving an MSDN level reason as to why this is, essentially classic mode wants every request to have a file extension.  If the request does not have a file extension, IIS will go look for that directory.  `Integrated` mode allows the request to go into the ASP.NET pipeline, which will then trigger your routing in your MVC site and the dynamic content will appear.

Comment: I've spent 2 hours trying to figure out whats wrong :) many thanks, it worked

Comment: @simsim  no sweat!  its always the little things that seem to cause the most headache :)

Comment: Yes indeed, sometimes looking too closely will let you mess the small things that is just a little far from where you are looking